# How to get information like firstname from Azure AD and use it in .net core?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-page-application

I want to show some information like firstname, mailadress, ... from Azure Active Directory in my SPA (Vue.js) using an ASP.NET Core Web Api. How can I get information from Azure Active Directory and use them in .NET Core?

Could be Microsoft Graph an opportunity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you authenticating your users? Are you using one of the OAuth2/OIDC flows to obtain tokens? If so, you can get an OIDC ID Token and use the claims within it to get that information so you can display it or use it from your application. For the basic user info you want, I don't see a need to use Graph

Comment: I'am using the Identity Server 4 (grant type: authorization flow PKCE). But I do not want to show only user data from the user who is logged in.

Comment: Ok, then yes you can use the Graph API as mentioned in the answer from Hari below. Is the idea to have your users make requests with their credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve it to MS Graph with the help of [users endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayname,givenName,mail,userPrincipalName
```

**Code Sample:**

```
const client = Client.init(options);

let res = await client.api('/users')
    .select('displayName,givenName,mail,userPrincipalName')
    .get();
```

> Note:  In Ms Graph users endpoint `givenName` is the first name field
> of the user.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have one more question. I found this article https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/overview/azure/activedirectory but I do not know which of these settings I have to add or to change and where I can get these information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @julius, Please go through a step-by-step tutorial which can help you [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core)

Comment: Hi @Hari, I read the step-by-step tutorial. I do not know how to integrate Microsoft Graph (application permission) in my ASP.NET Core project. I do not know what must be changed in Startup.cs ... . Can you support me please?

Comment: Please try the sample and if you stuck somewhere then please ask us the question.we will defiantly help you.